# Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password); returning null sometimes

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites

I am trying to enable self-registration in communities through sites but it is returning null randomly even when all the 3 values are populated. On the searching web, I found that we need to add forceSSl="True" but even after that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you do not have a password according to validations in your org it Site.createPortalUser returns null.